# Extracting Data from Another Domain, possible?

Tags: php, javascript, ruby-on-rails, cross-domain

I'm terrible at keeping track of my bills, so I wanted to create something automated. I also wanted the challenge of making it myself.

My questions:

Is it possible to have a webpage connect to another domain (any utility website i.e. timewarnercable.com) with the proper login credentials and retrieve the dollar amount I owe, then send me an email or even just display it on the webpage?

I've already got a webpage setup that has all my account info stored in it (don't worry it's only a local site!) and I can click a button and the info I have stored sends a POST request to the utility login site. This logs me in to my account page and then I can view the bill.  But don't want it to open another page..I'd rather load the content of that page in the background, scan for the code where its says my $ owed, then capture that somehow, then return the dollar amount onto the webpage.

If so, is this possible to design this with Ruby (Rails) or php, with Javascript / AJAX.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't completely understand your purposes but the curl library for php will allow you to do most of this with a little ajax help

Comment: First of all, it's illegal to extract data from another server without permission. They can prosecute you. There could be legal ways from how you can extract in the form of RESTful web services. Look for it. Then you can do what ever you want with them.

Answer (score 0):

What you're basically asking about is "page scraping", but your scenario is more complicated. You would have to fake the login post, capture and store any cookie/session info returned to you in the response and use that in subsequent requests to the site. You may also have to deal with redirects, depending on the site. 
I have found nodejs actually quite useful for scraping pages since it has plugins that provide dom selectors (there is a jquery plugin) - you're using javascript for server-side programming.
Check if the site has API and if the site provides that, will make your life a ton easier.
Some banks like BankOfAmerica have applications that already do this - they aggregate your accounts and bills from other sites, see if your bank can do this.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Sounds like a lot more work than I intended on putting into this. If I even get the free time to try this out, I'll let you know how it turns out!